# no of threads and ramp up combination

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have to make a report manually for jmeter and present the same to client and he' s asking for how many user does his website support but am unable to explain him.Because thread configuration say no of threads-100,ramp up time-100,then only 5 users are shown to be active via active thread through plugin but if I entered no of user to 100 and ramp up to be 1 sec,then it is showing 100 user is active.How's it possible and loop count is 1. 
Also what information should i present to him about the results because myself in graph or statistics is not clear,because am not able to understand the thread configuration.How and what figures should i entered in them.
Please give a general review,dont worry about the server details and environment.

Answer (score 0):

How long does this test run? If it's a very short script and it only runs for a minute or two, I could see your initial users finishing before the later ones start (with 100 second ramp time). If you shorten the ramp up, then they would probably run concurrently.

If this is your problem, make sure to add realistic think times to your users. This will make your script take longer and allow greater user concurrency.

Your other questions are important too, but this is the first step: make sure you understand what your test is doing before trying to get results from it.

Answer (score 0):

**Thread and Loop Count:**

Lets assume 1 user will take 5 seconds to execute your test plan!
You have 100 users and 100 seconds as ramp up period in the JMeter test plan.
You have loop count as 1.

It means JMeter will create (100 users/100 seconds => 1 user / sec) 1 user every sec. So, JMeter will create 100 users in 100 seconds.

**Remember that each user executes the test plan independently**. They do not depend on each other. Once the test plan is executed (as per the loop count) by a thread, It's job is done.

Now lets start the test and see what happens!!

- 1st Second: JMeter creates the first user.
- 2nd Second: JMeter creates the second user - while the first user has already started executing the test plan.
- 3rd second: 3rd user is created. 1st and 2nd users are executing the test plan.
- 4th second: 4th user is created. 1,2,3 - are in progress
- 5th second: 5th user is created. 1,2,3,4 are in progress. 1st user is about to finish as our testplan takes only 5 seconds to execute and the loop count is set to 1.

---

- 6th second: 6th user is created. 1st user finished the test plan. As the loop count is 1, the first user does not have to execute the test plan once again. So, it stops. 2,3,4,5 are in progress. 2nd user is about to finish.

Even if JMeter has created 6th user, the concurrent users are only 5. because the first user finished the test. So you will always have only 5 concurrent users from 6th second till 100th second.

....

Now you understand what is happening?

So..if you need 100 concurrent users, your test plan time for a single user should be more than your ramp up period. You can add timers to mimic real life scenario - so that the test takes more time to execute, or you can set the loop count to forever (in this case it will run forever - You can set the test duration to stop the test after the duration)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable feedback.Please tell me about execution time,as here you assume,so how can we know about the execution time,is there any kind of listeners for it.And in active user graph ,its going till the point 70 user under this configuration(No of user : 100
Ramp up time : 50,Loop Count : 20,Duration-5000 seconds),and after that,itis falling to 0.so website is behaving abnormally so is it its saturation point that more than 70 users in this particular scenario can't be handle.Till 70 concurrent users,it will perfectly run but above 70,its not possible?is it what graph is depicting.

Comment: Can you please tell me the execution time which you have assumed.Is there anyway to know what is the accurate execution time user has taken to finish it off.Also if loop count is 20 and users is arriving after say 3 seconds then in that moment,the previous  user which are given to loop 20 times, will going to stay even when next user arrives,or once it will loop 20 times and then next user arrives after 3 seconds.Please suggest.